# What release method contains?

Tags: objective-c

I was reading apple document in which I came across release method description.which says：

> The receiver is sent a dealloc message when its reference count reaches 0.

So, I was wondering what is definition of release method? Does it have condition which checks retain count? and if retain count is 0 then object is deallocated?

It would be helpful if anyone provides code snippet.

Comment: I don't understand your question. `release` does exactly what it says; what more do you want to know?

Comment: Is this just curiosity or do you have any problems in your code? If it's the latter you should not think about implementation details and solve your problem on a higher level.

Comment: @matthiasBauch It is just a curiosity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSObject's implementation was moved to the ObjC runtime in 10.9.   Thus, the implementation of NSObject is [open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/NSObject.mm).

```
- (oneway void)release
__attribute__((aligned(16)))
{
    // tagged pointer check is inside _objc_rootReleaseWasZero().

    if (_objc_rootReleaseWasZero(self) == false) {
        return;
    }
    [self dealloc];
}
```

You can read about `_objc_rootReleaseWasZero()` at the above link.  It is a deep rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer -

```
- (void)release
{
    if(NSDecrementExtraRefCountWasZero(self))
        [self dealloc];
}

BOOL NSDecrementExtraRefCountWasZero(id anObject)
{
    if(((struct obj_layout *)anObject)[-1].retained == 0){
        return YES;
    } else {
        ((struct obj_layout *)anObject)[-1].retained--;
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like the implementation from GNUstep and is entirely different, though same behavior, as the one used in iOS/OS X.  Namely, on iOS/OS X, the retain count may never be decremented to zero because there is no point in doing so (implementation detail, btw, and may change).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] init];  // Ref count is 1
[s retain];                             // Ref count is 2 - silly
                                        //   to do this after init
[s release];                            // Ref count is back to 1
[s release];                           // Ref count is 0, object is freed
```

The release method relinquishes ownership of an object. When a Cocoa object no longer has any owners, it may be deallocated — in which case it will automatically be sent a dealloc message.

Comment: I know how retain and release works. I want to know what is inside release method.

Comment: You already know what's inside `release`. It does what the spec says. If you want to see the literal source code to it, you're out of luck.